# Facebook apprequest dialog not open in mobile device browser

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I got the issue in my site with mobile devices browser. scenario for the issue is, we are displaying friends of the user which are login through my app. and near that user name we have given one invite button when user click on that invite button that facebook apprequest dialog will be open for that user. in that i passed user facebook user id. following is my code snippet.

```
FB.ui(
{ 
method: 'apprequests', message:'test message', to: 100007452844315, data: 'send-to-one-42' }, function(response) { if(!response.error_code && response.error_code!=4201) { $("#invite_"+arrId[1]).html("Invited"); $("#invite_"+arrId[1]).addClass("invited"); return false; }}
```

This works fine in my all desktop browser but when i open this page in my mobile (android,iphone) this feature is not working properly.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the exact same problem, only that i was able to "open" the apprequest dialogue on ipad and ipod.

no js debugging (and i did a lot of that including removing all external libraries other than FB) worked.

on iphone i got a blank page... but with the sourcecode of my site! intriguing i thought :)
the dialogue was in fact "open" but just not visible (oh the pain...)

what happened is this: we had `overflow: hidden` set inline on the body tag.
as you call the apprequest dialogue it adds the class `fb_hidden` to the body with this content:

```
-webkit-transform: none;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
top: -10000px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

since `overflow:visible` is now overwritten by the inline style guess what happened :) -> blank page!

why this only seems to be a problem on iphone and not on iPad and iPod remains a mystery to me... (maybe someone can shed some light on this?)

so either removing `overflow: hidden` from the body tag or overwriting the class `fb_hidden` with `overflow:visible!importent` did the trick and we now have a functional (ahm... visible) apprequest dialogue.

hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for your solution, reason of this problem is i have overwrite the css of #fb_root in my css and given z-index:0. that's why my popup is not working in mobile. i remove this property of the css and i solved my problem. thanks Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

It will only work if you set up your android  app, or ios app...., this is because facebook aplications are not visible form mobile devices.

Comment: i am not developing app of android and ios i am developing one website that's why i am using javascript sdk

Comment: then your app request never will visible for users who are using a mobile device!!!

Comment: i think you are not understanding my question :(